# React setState() запоздавшие обновление данных.Как это пофиксить?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.location.pathname !== this.props.location.pathname) {
            this.setState(function(prevState, props){
                console.log('test', document.location.pathname);
                console.log('test1', nextProps.location.pathname);
                return {path: nextProps.location.pathname}
            }.bind(this));
            console.log('update');
            this.pageUpdate(nextProps.location.pathname);
        }
        console.log('test2',this.state.path);
        console.log('componentWillReceiveProps');
    }
update
Page.jsx:33 test2 /page/time
Page.jsx:34 componentWillReceiveProps
Page.jsx:26 test /page/counters
Page.jsx:27 test1 /page/counters
```

Что ожидал увидеть

```
Page.jsx:26 test /page/counters
Page.jsx:27 test1 /page/counters
update
Page.jsx:33 test2 /page/time
Page.jsx:34 componentWillReceiveProps
```

[Тут говорится,](https://medium.com/@kanby/%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B2-setstate-%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-8fc7fa718eca) что первым параметром функция должна исправить такой казус.

Answer (score 0):

В самом React над описанием функции setState есть занятные комментарии:

> Sets a subset of the state. Always use this to mutate
>    state. You should treat `this.state` as immutable.
>
> There is no guarantee that `this.state` will be immediately updated,
>   so  accessing `this.state` after calling this method may return the
>   old value.
>
> There is no guarantee that calls to `setState` will run synchronously,
>   as they may eventually be batched together.  You can provide an
>   optional  callback that will be executed when the call to setState is
>   actually  completed.
>
> When a function is provided to setState, it will be called at some
>   point in  the future (not synchronously). It will be called with the
>   up to date  component arguments (state, props, context). These values
>   can be different  from this.* because your function may be called
>   after receiveProps but before  shouldComponentUpdate, and this new
>   state, props, and context will not yet be  assigned to this.
>
> @param {object|function} partialState Next partial state or function
>   to
>            produce next partial state to be merged with current state.  @param {?function} callback Called after state is updated.  @final
>   @protected

То есть создатели не гарантируют что сам вызов setState будет синхронным. Поэтому нужно использовать callback-функцию как второй аргумент для setState:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.location.pathname !== this.props.location.pathname) {
            this.setState(function(prevState, props){
                console.log('test', document.location.pathname);
                console.log('test1', nextProps.location.pathname);
                return {path: nextProps.location.pathname}
            }.bind(this),
                function() {
                    console.log('update');
                    this.pageUpdate(nextProps.location.pathname);
                    console.log('test2',this.state.path);
                    console.log('componentWillReceiveProps').bind(this);
                }
            );
        }
    }
```

Callback-функцию лучше вынести отдельно для читабельности кода,  но это уже совсем другая история

Comment: Я уже нашел этот момент.Пришлось копать внутри, и смотреть что и как делается там)

Comment: `setState`  - всегда асинхронный